# SQL Select with a set statement in it

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, set, case

I am trying to get the values for column `fpo` based on the values of other columns. The results are not in accordance with the `CASE` statement in the query. Can some one point me in a good direction?

```
   SELECT SL.[Document No_], SL.[Sell-to Customer No_], SL.Type, SL.[Line No_], ISNULL(PO.No_, 'BUY') AS RPO,
        CASE 
            WHEN PO.[Replan Ref_ No_] is null AND PO.[No_] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Neplanificata'
            WHEN PO.[Replan Ref_ No_] IS NULL AND PO.[No_] = 'Buy' THEN 'Buy'
            ELSE PO.[Replan Ref_ No_]
        END AS fpo
    FROM   [SC Vermorel SRL$Sales Line] AS SL 
    INNER JOIN [SC Vermorel SRL$Sales Header] AS SH ON SL.[Document No_] = SH.No_
    INNER JOIN [SC Vermorel SRL$Customer] AS Cust ON SL.[Sell-to Customer No_] = Cust.No_
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order] AS PO 
        ON (SH.[External Document No_] = PO.[Old Prod_ Order No_]) AND (PO.[Source No_] = SL.No_) AND (SL.Quantity = PO.Quantity)
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where do you define your variables? As far as I know, you cannot do an update in a SELECT statement.

Comment: Are you trying to update the table persistently, or do you just need a default value in case of `NULL`? The `SELECT` reads thata, the `SET` wants to **change** a value. For this you'd need an `UPDATE`. Please describe your needs.

Comment: Just need default values in case of certain criteria. Sorry I didn't specify correctly. I updated main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT SL.[Document No_], SL.[Sell-to Customer No_], SL.Type, SL.[Line No_], ISNULL(PO.No_, 'BUY') AS RPO,
        CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL(PO.[Replan Ref_ No_],'') = '' AND PO.[No_] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Neplanificata'
            WHEN ISNULL(PO.[Replan Ref_ No_],'') = '' AND ISNULL(PO.No_, 'BUY') = 'BUY' THEN 'Buy'
            ELSE PO.[Replan Ref_ No_]
        END AS fpo
    FROM   [SC Vermorel SRL$Sales Line] AS SL 
    INNER JOIN [SC Vermorel SRL$Sales Header] AS SH ON SL.[Document No_] = SH.No_
    INNER JOIN [SC Vermorel SRL$Customer] AS Cust ON SL.[Sell-to Customer No_] = Cust.No_
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order] AS PO 
        ON (SH.[External Document No_] = PO.[Old Prod_ Order No_]) AND (PO.[Source No_] = SL.No_) AND (SL.Quantity = PO.Quantity)
```

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work. I think CASE doesn't evaluate IS NOT NULL properly. What's more strange is that it doesn't work also for IS NULL, supposed to work. The second WHEN does nothing also, although the criteria is met.

Comment: No, `is not null` works correct  in `case` expression

Comment: Create temp table, fill it with test data, correct your query for this data and post this code with expected result in your question.

Comment: I added the output of the query with the code provided by you. As you can see, although the second conditions is met, the column `fpo` doesn't display the expected result.

Comment: Second condition works fine now! But first conditions still outputs blanks, although the condtition were met. See my edited question with a second capture.

Comment: @Catalin Cernat, try new version

Comment: you are the MAN! Thank you very much! Now i'll go chew the code you gave me to understand it. Cheers! Beers on me.

Comment: @Catalin Cernat, I'm glad to help you)